# How Toppling shifts from one edge to other in a polygon shaped body, without any external force applied

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Please explain that how the Toppling in a polygon shaped body shifts from one edge to the next adjacent edge while the object is already in motion, but without any sliding and no external force is applied. It will be better if you explain both ways, with and without including CoM.